# Um welchen Dialekt handelt es sich hierbei? (Dat Erdmänneken)

Tags: dialect

Das grimmsche Märchen "Dat Erdmänneken" beginnt wie folgt:

> Dat Erdmänneken
>
> Et was mal en rik Künig west, de hadde drei Döchter had, de wören alle
>   Dage in den Schlottgoren spazerengaen, un de Künig, dat was so en
>   Leivhawer von allerhand wackeren Bömen west: und einen, den hadde he
>   so leiv had, dat he denjenigen, de ünne Appel dervon plückede, hunnerd
>   Klafter unner de Ere verwünschede. As et nu Hervest was, da worden de
>   Appel an den einen Baume so raut ase Blaud. De drei Döchter gungen
>   alle Dage unner den Baum un seihen to, ov nig de Wind 'n Appel
>   herunnerschlagen hädde, awerst se sannen ehr Levedage kienen, un de
>   Baum de satt so vull, dat he breken wull un de Telgen (Zweige) hungen
>   bis up de Ere. Da gelusted den jungesten Künigskinne gewaldig, un et
>   segde to sinen Süstern: "Use Teite (Vater) de hett us viel to leiv,
>   ase dat he us verwünschen deihe: ik glöve, dat he dat nur wegen de
>   frümden Lude dahen hat." Un indes plücked dat Kind en ganz dicken
>   Appel af un sprunk fur sinen Süstern un segde: "A, nu schmeket mal,
>   mine lewen Süsterkes, nu hew ik dock min Levedage so wat Schones no
>   nig schmecket." Da beeten de beiden annern Künigsdöchter auk mal in
>   den Appel, un da versünken se alle drei deip unner de Ere, dat kien
>   Haan mer danach krehete.

Hier der eingescannte Ausschnitt in Fraktur:

[image: Dat Erdmänneken Ausschnitt (wie oben zitiert)]

Um welchen Dialekt handelt es sich denn dabei? Ich würde auf irgendwas Niederdeutsches tippen, aber das widerspricht wiederum meines Wissens der Gegend in der die Märchen wohl vor allem gesammelt wurden.

Weiß jemand mehr?

Vielleicht kann sogar jemand eine Vorgehensweise für derlei Fragen umreißen. Also welche Quellen sollte man bemühen und so weiter ...

Comment: Um das noch zu ergänzen, ich hatte [hier gefragt](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1154) ob eine derartige Frage hier zulässig wäre.

Comment: Sieht definitiv nach einem plattdeutschen Dialekt aus. Wie kommst du darauf, dass Märchen nicht in Norddeutschland gesammelt wurden? *Vom Fischer un siner Fru* ist ja zum Beispiel durchaus eines der bekannteren grimmschen Märchen.

Comment: @Chieron: allein eine _Vermutung_ meinerseits. Wenn sie Unsinn sein sollte, freue ich mich über Aufklärung des Irrtums.

Comment: Ich denke, dass Märchen überall im deutschen Sprachraum gesammelt wurden. Im Niederdeutschen Sprachraum werden vermutlich fast dieselben Märchen erzählt worden sein - und dann nur eine hochdeutsche Variante (derer es sicher auch mehrere gab) in die endgültige Sammlung aufgenommen. Märchen die einzig hier erzählt wurden, wären aber nicht übersetzt worden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laut [Anmerkungsband](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Kinder-_und_Haus-M%C3%A4rchen_Band_3_(1856)/Anmerkungen#91) der Grimms stammt [dieses Märchen in der abgedruckten Version](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Dat_Erdm%C3%A4nneken) aus dem Paderborner Raum und sie verzeichnen auch eine abweichende Variante aus Köln.

> #### 91. Dat Erdmänneken.
>
> Aus dem Paderbörnischen. Eine andere Erzählung aus der Gegend von Cöln am Rhein weicht in einigem ab.

Der Dialekt dürfte also einem ostwestfälischen Platt aus dem späten 18. oder frühen 19. Jahrhundert entsprechen, da es bereits in der Erstausgabe 1815 auftaucht. Ich hätte es auch eher südlich eingeschätzt, z.B. wegen *schmecken* statt *smecken*, aber allein aufgrund meines oberflächlichen Grimm-Wissens eher den Göttinger Raum angenommen.

Für die Grimms ist Wikisource, das ich verlinkt habe, meist ziemlich hilfreich und vollständig. Bei weniger populären Autoren oder Werken kann das ganz anders aussehen.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank. Mir war der Anmerkungsband nicht geläufig. Muß ich mir einmal besorgen.

Comment: Ganz richtig! Meine Mutter stammt aus der Gegend am Möhnesee und, wenngleich ich nie dort gelebt habe, kann ich bestätigen, dass dort so ähnlich gesprochen wird. Ob ich das jetzt allerdings als Platt akzeptieren kann... Ich würde sagen, sogar das hier ist nur Platt-light: http://www.radiobremen.de/bremeneins/serien/plattdeutsche_nachrichten/audio168536-popup.html